# Custom top-bar back text in ZURB's Foundation

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

When I add this code to my application.js it doesn't work properly.
I displays 2 more 'custom_text' button and it keeps there the original 'back' button.

```
    $(document).foundation()
        .foundation('topbar', {
            index : 0,
            stickyClass : 'sticky',
            custom_back_text: true,
            back_text: 'custom_text',
            init : true
        });
```

How could be that fixed?

Answer (score 6):

Foundation Topbar now supports data-options, eg.

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-section data-options="back_text: 'custom_text'">
```

Comment: I'm curious to know where this is documented (for version 5)? I mean this particular data-options attribute as well as others. Where will one find out about it?

Comment: @Henrik you should start reading docs from the very beginning next time :P
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are initializing two times the foundation script. You can fix it in this way:

```
$(document).foundation('topbar', {
        index : 0,
        stickyClass : 'sticky',
        custom_back_text: true,
        back_text: 'custom_text',
        init : true
    });
```

Comment: Didn't work with the zurb-foundation (4.3.1) gem. Don't know why.